# How can I get `emacs -nw` to work with xterm using UTF-8 locale?

Tags: emacs, utf-8, xterm

I'm using Emacs 23 with `xterm` and am trying to bring my Linux system into the 21st century by switching from a `POSIX` locale to `en_US.utf8`.  Problem: when I use the Alt key on the keyboard in this locale, `xterm` sends a two-character sequence.  I'd like to fix emacs so that it sees, e.g., `Alt-f` as meta-f rather than the two-character sequence `"\303\246"`.  I think this might be a job for an input coding, but from the emacs documentation I have not figured out how to write one.

As an alternative I would be willing to add octal `'\303'` to a keymap so that emacs would treat it as a prefix character to introduce a meta escape.  The way I would prefer to do this would be to bind `'\303'` to a function that then takes the next key and adjusts it as a meta key. But I can't quite figure out that one either.

Worst case I guess I write a loop that binds the meta keys for `'a'` through `'z'` or something equally horrid.

I've messed around with the `set-terminal-coding-system`, but the crux of the matter is that in a UTF-8 locale, `xterm` uses the Alt key to send non-ascii characters—the Alt key no longer behaves like meta.  So setting the terminal coding system to UTF-8 merely enables me to enter Latin characters with diacritical marks.  Not the behavior I hoped for.

I found a really horrid answer that involves guessing what `xterm` is doing around the meta key.  Suggestions for improvement are welcome—I'd like to find code that could do this job cleanly.

(And FYI, [I'm not the only one with this problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.emacs.help/KEk5K_YBsOY/EJkTkN9PDt4J).)

Comment: have you tried to set it via `set-terminal-coding-system`? What returns `M-: (terminal-coding-system)`? If I understand correctly, the problem maybe that your Alt isn't translated into Meta - check the terminal settings

Comment: @AlexOtt neither `nil` nor `utf-8` works.  I think the fault lies in `xterm`, not in `emacs`.  This is really a workaround for weird stuff that `xterm` does.  For example, using rxvt, `emacs -nw` "just works" with the Alt keys.

Comment: man [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html), see [eightBitInput](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:eightBitInput).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a truly horrible hack:

```
(unless (display-graphic-p)
  (defun make-meta-key ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((e (read-event)))
      (if (numberp e)
          (let ((keys  (vector (event-convert-list (list 'meta
                                                        (+ (event-basic-type e) 64))))))
            (let ((result (key-binding keys)))
              (command-execute result)))
        (error "this can't happen"))))
  (global-set-key [?\M-C] 'make-meta-key))
```

This seems to work around what `xterm` is doing.

**ETA**: revision to handle more meta sequences:

`(unless (display-graphic-p)
  ;; deal with the Unicode sequences that xterm sends when Alt (meta) keys
  ;; are used. N.B. Works with Alt-letter, Alt-\, Alt-space, and Alt-Shift-:
  (defun make-meta-key ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((e (read-event)))
      ;; (message "Got event %s; basic event is %s" e (event-basic-type e))
      (if (numberp e)
          (let* ((basic (event-basic-type e))
                 (shifted (+ basic 64))
                 (basecode (if (<= shifted 127) shifted basic))
                 (keys (vector (event-convert-list (list 'meta basecode))))
                 (command (key-binding keys)))
              ;; (message "Result is %s; commandp says %s" command (commandp command))
              (command-execute command))
        (error "this can't happen"))))
  (global-set-key [?\M-C] 'make-meta-key)
  (defun do-nothing () (interactive) nil)
  (global-set-key [?\M-B] 'do-nothing))`